# textarea is not auto adjusting its size

Tags: css, frontend

I am creating a form with a `textarea`, which should contain voluminous text and which can expand depending on the volume of the entered text, but in my case it does not change its size when the volume of the entered text changes

This is CSS for the form:

```
.paste-text {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar */
    resize: none; /* Disable manual resizing */
    height: auto; /* Automatically adjust height based on content */
}
```

This is HTML code of the form:

```
<div>
    <form className="paste-form" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
            <textarea
                className="paste-text"
                id="text"
                name="text"
                placeholder="Write here the text of your paste"
                value={formik.values.text}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
            />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Create paste"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to make textarea auto-adjusting to the entered text

Comment: Please post the generated HTML and the template in order to create a [mre]

Comment: `overflow-y: hidden` will not simply hide the scrollbar, but also clipped the content which stop the textarea from growing. Check out the [example on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss3_overflow-y)

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can not adjust the text area height by using only CSS. You have to use some JavaScript code to resize the height when text is entered:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Auto-adjust Textarea Height</title>
    <style>
        textarea {
            resize: none; /* Disable textarea resizing */
            overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar initially */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <textarea id="autoAdjustTextarea" oninput="autoAdjustHeight(this)"></textarea>

    <script>
        function autoAdjustHeight(textarea) {
            // Reset the height to default to get the scroll height
            textarea.style.height = 'auto';

            // Set the new height based on the scroll height
            textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

1. The `textarea` has an `oninput` attribute that calls the autoAdjustHeight JavaScript function whenever the user enters text.
2. The CSS styles include `resize: none;` to prevent manual resizing of the `textarea` and `overflow-y: hidden;` to hide the vertical scrollbar initially.
3. The `autoAdjustHeight` function is responsible for adjusting the `textarea` height based on its scroll height. It sets the height to 'auto' first to get the scroll height and then updates the `textarea` height accordingly.